# Render partial with object, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, partial

I am stuck in basic stuff.

I have subscribes controller and I created form partial, so I could make new subscribtion from contact page.

My partial looks like this :

```
<%= form_for(@subscribe) do |f| %>
  <% if @subscribe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscribe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscribe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @subscribe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am rendering partial using this code inside contact/index page :

```
<%= render 'subscribes/form', :locals => { :subscribe => @subscribe} %>
```

After this I get such error :

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

I tried to change object names , some syntax from similair sugestions in stuck overflow.

Like :

```
render "subscribes/form", collection: @subscribe
render :partial => 'subscribes/form', :object => Subscribe.new
```

I guess I am doing something completely wrong or some damm simple mistake. I am doing. :)

Comment: Passing the arguments of a partial with local is correct, but in the partial template there's no mention of a model_name attribute. Is it the case that the error is somewhere else?

Comment: @lucke84  I think it happens because it cant recognize partials object.Because when I remove partial render, page loads just fine without bugs.

Comment: Try without passing variable. `<%= render '/subscribes/form' %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you are not using passed argument at all in your view - it would be `subscribe`, not `@subscribe`. It does not change the fact it should work as instance variable should be set. It looks like it is set to nil - you need to check your controller action and find out why is that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a typo, the first time you implemented the partial you've written this:

```
<%= render 'subscribes/form', :locals => { :subscribe => @subscribe} %>
```

While it should be:

```
<%= render :partial => 'subscribes/form', :locals => { :subscribe => @subscribe} %>
```

Furthermore, the partial should not refer to the `@subscribe` variable, but to `subscribe` (with no @), since it's the variable name your passing to the template.

Comment: There's no difference - inside the view `render` renders with partial as a default.